How do I update a column in a DataFrame with a column from another DataFrame where the key in both DataFrames has duplicates?
I have two DataFrames. In both DataFrames, the key has duplicates and I'm OK with that. I want the product column in the target DataFrame to be updated with the product value in the first DataFrame. When I use .update() I get errors because of duplicate values. Can this be done in one step somehow?
I'd like the product in the target df to match the product in the source df. In other words, I'd like to use the source to update the target file. The product associated with a key can indeed change over time, hence the effort to update the target.
I hope that helps - happy to provide more detail!
import pandas as pd 

source = {
"Employee ID": [123, 456, 456, 123],
"Product": ['abc', 'def', 'def', 'abc']} 

target = {
"Employee ID": [123, 456, 456, 123],
"Product": ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']}

target_transformed = {
"Employee ID": [123, 456, 456, 123],
"Product": ['abc', 'def', 'def', 'abc']}

source_df = pd.DataFrame(source)
target_df = pd.DataFrame(target)
result = pd.DataFrame(target_transformed)

result


To be able to answer your question unambiguously, can you please provide a complete [mre]? Ideally a DataFrame constructor for each input and the matching expected output. Also, please explain if the "product" will always match a given "key".

It's actually not so straightforward, you need to perform a merge after de-duplication:
target_df['Product'] = (target_df[['Employee ID']]
  .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('Employee ID').cumcount())
  .merge(source_df.assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby('Employee ID').cumcount()),
         on=['Employee ID', 'n'], how='left')
  ['Product'].values
)

Modified target_df:
   Employee ID Product
0          123     abc
1          456     def
2          456     def
3          123     abc


you can use np.where:
import numpy as np
target_df['Product']=np.where(target_df['Employee ID']==source_df['Employee ID'],source_df['Product'],target_df['Product'])

